# How to type en-dash and em-dash in Windows 7/8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, typing

I write blog posts, and I often need to type en-dash (–) and sometimes em-dash (—) in my blog posts. Currently I keep these characters saved in a text file, and copy-paste them whenever I need them. Unnecessary to say, it is a headache to move between keyboard and mouse when you type large texts.

It would be better for me if there ware a keyboard shortcuts available for these two characters. Is there a way to type en-dash and em-dash in Windows? I use Windows 7 and Windows 8 in different computers.

---

Here's an aligned comparison of dashes, if you need to see the difference for some reason.

1. Here's-dash
2. Here's–en-dash
3. Here's—em-dash

Comment: Your #1 is a "hyphen-minus". It is also important not to confuse these with U+2212: MINUS SIGN (−).

Comment: The accepted answer is great, but I want to add that you don't need the mouse to copy and paste the dashes from your text file. Assuming you have your text file and the document you're typing open in two different windows, when you get to the spot where you want a dash, you can:
1. Use Alt+Tab to switch between them
2. Use the arrow keys to get to the dash you want
3. Hold down Shift+Arrow key to highlight the dash
4. Ctrl+C to copy
5. Alt+Tab back to your document
6. Ctrl+V to paste

Comment: If you don't mind using a 3rd party tool, I'd recommend WinCompose. en-dash is then `[hotkey]--.` and em-dash `[hotkey]---`

Comment: Depending on where you’re from, there may be appropriate keyboard layouts (like German T2).

Comment: Pragmatical way for infrequent use and with a laptop without a numerical keyboard or num lock: google for "en dash windows" and copy/paste from characters from this post.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have a numpad, turn numlock on and use `Alt + 0150` for en-dash and `Alt + 0151` for em-dash. That is keep Alt pressed and type the numbers on the numeric keypad.

EDIT: As @gronostaj points out, this works with only left Alt.

Comment: It's worth noting that it works only with left Alt.

Comment: @gronostaj: Thanks for the info. Luckily I typed with left `alt`. Otherwise I would not have accepted the answer.

Comment: Just checked, this works for me with right Alt as well. I was using autohotkey to map right Alt to left Alt for a while but not anymore. Maybe it is keyboard dependent

Comment: It also requires a 10-key.

Comment: Well in my laptop I can use both `alt` keys as well.

Comment: Right Alt works for me, too.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work for other numbers, not numpad.

Comment: I know this is the correct answer, but I want to downvote just because how stupid this method is. What's the deal, Microsoft?

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for a slightly faster (although not-native) solution, I have made an AutoHotKey program that lets you type Em and En dashes *somewhat* naturally. I really made it for myself, but it's on [Github](https://github.com/CemraJC/em-n-en/) if anyone's interested.

[It's called Em-n-en.](https://github.com/CemraJC/em-n-en/releases/latest)

The entire point of this program is to allow a user to quickly insert an
em/en dash by typing `==-` (Em dash) or `--=` (En dash).  There are other
methods for inserting the dashes - these are covered in the program itself.
Note that this only works on windows.

Hopefully this is helpful! :)

Comment: Could you possible expand on how the OP would make use of your software? Please see [How to recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Comment: +1 for clever and appropriate use of a candy name for your AHK script.  It would be nice to see the actual code in your answer.

Answer (score 8):

As of Windows 10 Version 1903, you can enter en-dash, em-dash, and various other symbols in a much simpler way using the updated Emoji panel:

[image]

Just type `Win` + `.` (or `Win` + `;`) and select the omega symbol on the top of the panel.

If you don't want to take your hands off the keyboard, you can select the omega symbol using TAB and arrow keys.

Comment: Yass! Winner on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

To find any character you need, use "Character Map" - note the text in the lower right corner.
Note also that the availabilty of a character depends on the typeface (Font) that you have active.

[image: WindowsXP version]

You use Character map to find out which character and what "Keystroke" (above) it can be generated with. Then you do not need Character map any more - assumed you can remember the number or keys to type/use. Note that some are available also with Alt/Shift/Control - as in <del>Alt+Space</del> == either of Em or En space **(can't remember which it is right now and no W-computer to try it out on)**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Character map is how I initially found the two characters. My requirement was that I should not need to move my hand to mouse from my keyboard. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Yes? You use `Character map` *to find out* which character and what "Keystroke" (above) it can be generated with. Then you do not need `Character map` any more - assumed you can remember the number or keys to type/use. Note that some are available also with Alt/Shift/Control - as in Alt+Space == either of Em or En space (can't remember which it is right now and no W-computer to try it out on).

Comment: This may help also: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-special-characters-character-map-faq#1TC=windows-7 - especially "How do I create private character"

Comment: And this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21187/insert-any-special-character-with-a-single-keystroke/

Comment: @Hannu Alt+Space just opens the current window's system menu (the one with restore, move, close...). Some programs, like Microsoft Word, may have other shortcuts for em and en dashes, but the only shortcut that works everywhere is the Alt+numpad key combination.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, you can use a clipboard manager like [ClipX](https://bluemars.org/clipx/) with the "Stickies" plugin. If you store proper en dash into the list, entering it is just **Ctrl+Alt+V** (or whatever shortcut is configured to show the list) followed by **A**.

Answer (score 0):

Via [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/):

Create a script like `dashes.ahk` somewhere on your computer:

```
; en dash
::--::–

; bonus point: em dash
::---::—
```

Make sure it's stored as **UTF-8 with BOM**. Double click it and try typing `--` followed by space somewhere; it will replace it with n-dash.

Similarly for m-dash.