# Is there single-keystroke way to type an em dash in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use em dashes a lot. For example:

> The rat race was over. The rats — to no one's surprise — had won.

**My question:** In Windows is there a **single keystroke** that will type an em dash **that doesn't require a number pad?**

Or is there a way to configure Windows to emit an em dash upon the entypement of a given key-combination, like maybe through the registry or some "shortcuts" functionality or something?

**I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/811318/how-to-type-en-dash-and-em-dash-in-windows-7-8).** The accepted answer does provide a way to type an em dash, but it requires four keystrokes and a number pad. Hence, this is a new question, not a repetition of that previous one.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: MS Word supports Alt+Ctrl+ - (minus) That or copy one to the clipboard and paste when needed.

Comment: Maybe you can (re)map (another) key (combination)?. See https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key

Answer (score 1):

Just use the - key (the one between 0 and =) Word will - automatically - convert it to a – (en-dash) as soon as you add a space after the next word you type! :-)

PS: see what I did there with the dashes? ;-)

Comment: For the typographically pedantic, an en-dash is not an em-dash, and it's nigh blasphemy to interchange them.