# How to type mdash and ndash characters in Windows 10 on a UK English keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, special-characters

In HTML, they are called the `&ndash;` and `&mdash;` entities.

Here is how they look like:

> –      hyphen
> –      en dash (or ndash, en-dash or n-dash)
> —      em dash (or mdash, em-dash or m-dash)

Here is an article about them: https://www.punctuationmatters.com/hyphen-dash-n-dash-and-m-dash/

I have found a way in Ubuntu, it goes by hitting the minus/underscore key two or three times (for n- and m-dash correspondingly) while holding down the right "Windows" key.

Now I would like to type them while on Windows too. How?

Comment: Ah, it did not occur to me to search for the hyphen-divided naming variants!

Comment: Also — thank you! (For Windows 10: https://superuser.com/a/1476207/1257174)